# Problems with adding PhantomJSDriverService to the driver

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium, webdriver, phantomjs

I have a question. How can I add a PhantomJSDriverService to the driver without opening another driver? Or closing both drivers at the end?

What I have works, BUT it opens 2 drivers and when the program ends it only closes one of them. And the other one keeps running until I shut it down via task manager.

So, what I have is this.
At the start of the code I create a driver:

```
IWebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver();
```

After creating this driver I call, somewhere else in the code, the PhantomJSDriverService:

```
            PhantomJSDriverService service = PhantomJSDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
            service.IgnoreSslErrors = true;
            service.LoadImages = false;
            service.ProxyType = "none";
```

I call it somewhere else in the code because if I call it before I can't set the 
service values.

To add the service to the driver I use this after the setting the service values:

```
driver = new PhantomJSDriver(service);
```

But when I do this it creates another driver. So... Is it possible to close the second driver afterwards? Or Is there another solution for it?

This is my CleanUp method:

```
public void CleanUp()
    {
        if (driver != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Closed browser");
            driver.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try and start the driver up later in the process like below

```
PhantomJSDriverService service = PhantomJSDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
service.IgnoreSslErrors = true;
service.LoadImages = false;
service.ProxyType = "none";

IWebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(service);
```

Comment: Yeah, but the driver is needed at the beginning of the code, because it needs to be declared before using it.

Comment: @JoshC ah ok, so your using the driver and then later changing it's properties?

Comment: Well yes, because you can't change it's properties if the declaration is not in a method. (At the very start of the code). Is there a better way to change its properties?

Comment: @JoshC Interesting, I've never come across the need to change the properties later in the drivers existence. Why can't you new up the driver and set the properties straight after? I think this makes more sense since it's the whole setup process.

Comment: Well I need to change them because otherwise the java script isn't working somehow. How can I change the properties straight after?

Comment: @JoshC In my example code that is what I mean, set everything up and then  `new PhantomJSDriver(service)`

Comment: Yeah I get that, but I can't set everything up because the "service" is getting an error: 'ConsoleApplication2.Program.service' is a 'field' but is used like a 'type'. And to add the service to the driver I need to make the driverservice static.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to not instantiate it until you need it. By this I mean just assign it to `null` to begin with;

```
 IWebDriver driver = null;
```

...do all the service-related stuff you are doing and then just do as before:

```
driver = new PhantomJsDriver();
```